# What is the maximum effective size of a socket send buffer in Linux?

Tags: linux, sockets, udp

I'm aware of the `net.core.wmem_max` parameter to `sysctl` that controls the maximum socket buffer size that I'm able to request via `setsockopt()`. However, there seems to be a more fundamental limitation that I'm running into. A summary of my scenario:

I have a device that I'm trying to send UDP datagrams to at a high rate. The device and my NIC support Ethernet flow control, so it is able to communicate to my system when it can't accept any more data to rate-limit the stream. This should make it so my application can just push data into the socket as fast as it can, and the calls to `send()` should block when the send buffer gets full, until there is room to queue the datagram.

To a degree, this works as expected; the system (via `netstat`, GNOME System Monitor, etc.) reports that the total outbound network traffic is, on average, the expected rate. However, what I've noticed is that, depending on the buffer size that I request, I may or may not get the backpressure that I expect.

In all of my tests, I've set `net.core_wmem_max = 100000000` (100 MB). I am running Ubuntu 18.04. I've noticed two regimes of operation, based on the send buffer size that I request via `setsockopt()` with `SO_SNDBUF` as the option:

- **size = 10 MB:** In this case, the test works properly; once the socket send buffer gets to its limit, `send()` blocks as expected.
- **size = 100 MB:** In this case, I see the desired rate output to the network via `netstat`, but if I compare that to the amount of data that I pass into the socket via `send()`, it is clear some data is being dropped. For example, I might have a network data rate of 640 MB/sec, but if I sum up the return values of all of the successful calls to `send()`, I'm actually pushing 800 MB/sec into the socket. I am properly error-checking all of my `send()` calls to ensure that none of them have failed.

  If I use `/proc/net/udp` to monitor the size of the send buffer (via the `tx_queue` column), it shows that the send buffer only ever gets to around 32 MB in size, and never any larger. This implies that there is some fundamental limit to the send queue length, but since it never hits the configured capacity of 100 MB, `send()` doesn't block and instead the data gets thrown on the floor. The man page to `send()` alludes to this possibility:

> ```
>    ENOBUFS
>           The  output queue for a network interface was full.  This generally indicates that the inter‐
>           face has stopped sending, but may be caused by transient congestion.   (Normally,  this  does
>           not occur in Linux.  Packets are just silently dropped when a device queue overflows.)
> ```

However, I'm unable to find any authoritative information on what scenarios might cause packets to be dropped silently. It doesn't seem I can trust the send buffer capacity that I request, so what is the maximum **effective** size of a socket send buffer in Linux?

Comment: You might try calling getsockopt() after your setsockopt() call succeeds, it will tell you what the buffer size was *actually* set to (which may or may not be the same as what you requested it to be set to)

Comment: Good idea. I tried that previously, and it reports the value that you would expect. That is, if I request a size of 100 MB, it returns 200 MB (due to the documented doubling that it does of the requested size). However, even as it reports the larger buffer size, I still see the artificial limiting at approximately 32 MB, and the associated lack of blocking and dropping of datagrams instead.